# WSO2 ESB 4.5.0 sample axis2 server cannot be started (samples.util.SampleAxis2Server)

Tags: wso2-esb

WSO2 ESB 4.5.0 sample axis2 server cannot be started (samples.util.SampleAxis2Server)

```
D:\esb-4.5.0\samples\axis2Server>axis2server.bat
 "Starting Sample Axis2 Server ..."
 Using AXIS2_HOME:      D:\axis2
 Using JAVA_HOME:       C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_33
 Server could not start due to class loading issue java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: samples.util.SampleAxis2Server
```

thanks to Shelan Perera. sample axis2 server is working.

---

I got new exceptions after executing sample client.

client:

```
ERROR {org.apache.sandesha2.SandeshaModule} -  Could not load module policies. Using default values.
```

ESB:

```
Heap dump file created [1178627263 bytes in 45.317 secs]
WARN - TimeoutHandler Expiring message ID : urn:uuid: ee4eeea8-1dd0-4704-8914-074c6cee40ae;
dropping message after global timeout of : 120 seconds
Exception in thread "[Timer] - Periodical Task (Bundle 124) (Bundle 124)"
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:Java heap space[2012-10-25 10:13:10,070] ERROR - NativeWorkerPool
Uncaught exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
ERROR - NativeWorkerPool Uncaught exception
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "NHTTPLatencyView-nio-http-latency-view" java.lang.OutOfMemo
Exception in thread "PoolCleaner[28471793:1351129604388]" java.lang.OutOfMemoryE
Exception in thread "http-sender-connections-view" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: 
Exception in thread "NHTTPS2SLatencyView-nio-http-latency-view" java.lang.OutOfM
ERROR - CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask Error while running deployment synchronizer
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you defined AXIS2_HOME environment variable ? If so remove that and try. You can see that

```
Using AXIS2_HOME:      D:\axis2
```

is not using some other server. (I tried to start server in windows and started successfully.)

Comment: Have you started ESB with some port offset?

Comment: Nope. My ESB is running at port 9443: <Offset>0</Offset>

Answer (score 1):

In Linux you can do this

Go to home folder

press Ctrl + h (to show hidden file)

Open .bashrc file

If $AXIS2_HOME is defined remove it and then add

```
 export AXIS2_HOME=""
 export PATH=$PATH:$AXIS2_HOME
```

This will remove even if you downloaded Axis2 from apt-get